# Kubernetes pod can not resolve domain name if it is running on a specific node

Tags: networking, kubernetes

We have an on premises Kubernetes cluster, running on nodes with hostnames node1.mycompany.local through node7.mycompany.local. We also have a database server on node16.mycompany.local, outside the Kubernetes cluster.

When a pod runs on node4 or node7, it can not resolve database domain name and fails. If I move the pod to a different node other than 4 or 7, it can connect to the database and runs without a problem.

When I ssh into any of the nodes in the cluster, I can ping to the database server by hostname without any problems.

When running a docker container directly without Kubernetes, we specify extra hostnames alongside IP's for the container to resolve, but I don't know how Kubernetes is handling this, because I couldn't find any config which specifies IP's of the external nodes.

My kubernetes version is:

```
Client Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.0"...
Server Version: version.Info{Major:"1", Minor:"9", GitVersion:"v1.9.5+coreos.0",...
```

What can cause this problem?

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using so outdated version of K8s?

Comment: There isn't a technical reason. People knowledgeable about this stuff left the company and we aren't comfortable enough with it to take the risk of updating.